# Can we highlight single word of from Text Property (have multiple words)of Label Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, infragistics

I am Using infragistics Controls in Window Application.

I have put multiple words in `Label`’s `Text` Property, now want to highlight single word from Label Text.

Comment: highlight means? explain

Comment: In a winforms standard label you need owner-drawing to highlight text portions or change fonts or colors. Infragistics I don't know. Are you trargetting winforms? WPF?..??

Comment: hi i want to set fore color or back color of single word of label Text

Answer (score 1):

The Infragistics [UltraFormattedLinkLabel](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/2015.1/CLR4.0/?page=WinFormattedLinkLabel_Formatting_Text_and_Hyperlinks.html) allows you to set the color of the text for a single word:

```
<font color="red">Red Text</font> <font color="green">Green Text</font> <font color="#0000ff">Blue Text</font>
```

Comment: PLEASE read my question again i am asking for window application ....................ok

Comment: That is for a Windows Application, see the help for the UltraFormattedLinkLabel for more details: http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/2015.1/CLR4.0/?page=WinFormattedLinkLabel_Formatting_Text_and_Hyperlinks.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Infragistics, in your code you can try:

```
ultraFormattedLinkLabel1.Value = "This is in <b>Bold</b>";
```

Another way, using a standard rich text box set to readonly and no borders:

```
richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
richTextBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \b bold\b0.}";
```